# button not shown in alertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I m creating a class that extends AlertDialog. and setting layout. But when pop up is called,

**1) layout is transparent

2) buttons not visible even after calling setButton **
I don't know what to do with , and no Idea why its happening.

My classes are this
DateTimeDialog.java

```
public class DateTimeDialog extends AlertDialog{

    Date date;
    String title;
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener listner;
    protected DateTimeDialog(Context context, String title, Date date ) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void initListener(DialogInterface.OnClickListener listner){
        this.listner = listner;
    }

    public Date getDate(){


        return date;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.date_time_picker);



        setTitle(title);

        setButton( "OK", listner);

        setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
                new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do something
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }
```

method that is calling this class

```
final DateTimeDialog dateTimeDialog = new DateTimeDialog(context, "title", time);
           dateTimeDialog.show();
           dateTimeDialog.initListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //doSomething
                }
            });
```

Please help.....

Comment: I think you should use .setPositiveButton(...) and .setNegativeButton(...)

Comment: Since I m extending AlertDialog, so I don't need to add '.' to it.

Comment: I meant use setPositiveButton and setNegativeButton. Have you tried that?

Comment: thanx for reply. and YesI tried that, no help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call setContentView, you override any and all content the AlertDialog class provides. If you want to set the content view yourself, you need to add the buttons in the XML file and set listeners.

Comment: ohh... Is that so. ok in that case I will try that only. But what If i want that the buttons to b generic as it is in default alert dialog

Comment: if I am adding button from layout, and adding listner its listner is not responding even on click!!!!????