# Pop up is not called from spinner

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-spinner

with ref. to my previous question [View.onClickListner not called from other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993583/view-onclicklistner-not-called-from-other-class)

I have a Date time dialog  which is called my this method

```
public static void markTime(final String ref){
        myClass c = new myClass();

        if(c.getTime() == null)
        {
            c.setTime(Utils.getCurrentDateTime());
        }
        else
        {
           final DateTimeDialog dateTimeDialog = new DateTimeDialog(context, "title", c.getTime());
           dateTimeDialog.show();
           dateTimeDialog.initListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    c.setTime(dateTimeDialog.getDate());
                    dateTimeDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I am calling markTime() and various places in my app and working fine, but when called in spinner, its not showing pop up. My code for spinner is

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> itemName, View view, int pos, long id) {
            switch(pos)
            {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(instance, "markTime0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                com.acs.inurse.common.Utils.markTime(ref);
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(instance, "markTime1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                com.acs.inurse.common.Utils.markTime(caseRef);
                break;
            }
        }
```

The pop is not called from spinner. Where I am getting wrong I don't know. or I am not including some code???
please help!!!!

**Note** toast is shown but not pop up on every time selection change

Comment: do you get any error messages in logcat?

Comment: No, no error on logcat. even on debug, cursor goes  inside the code but its not displaying pop up, which in turn is called at other places where i used the same code.

Comment: Where is the `context` coming from?

Comment: I have defined it from my activity.
Like MyActivity.instance
and declared inMActivity that instance

Comment: What is the code of `myClass`? are you sure you are not getting into the if clasue of your if\else construct in `markTime`?

Comment: I am getting inside if/else clause, and even show() , but pop for date time is not shown on emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for all the trouble. I got the answer.
It was just that, I was passing the wrong context to DateTimeDialog. 
Say I needed to the DateTimeDialog from Activity1, but I was passing the context of Acivity 2.

Thanks for all the help,